# Call model from another controller in joomla

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla3.4

I am developing Joomla 3.4 application.

I want to `get model` of menus item controller into another topic controller.

When I run below code in menus item controller then call model

```
$model    = $this->getModel('item', '', array());
```

But when this code run in topic controller then `nothing display (NULL)`

```
How to call model into another controller?
```

What problem I am facing. Any one have a idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model  = $this->getModel('Checkout');
$data   = $model->getPriceBetween($pid);
```

Then you need to put query in `getPriceBetween` function in checkout model.